# PHP API Paging loop

Tags: php, api, loops, while-loop, paging

I have this code

I need a loop to be able to print all results which are 400-600 but I'm not able because I'm limited to only 100 shows per page and I need a loop/while to make the same request but changing the page and then print the result and I'm not able to make it, can someone explain me how to implement here a loop or to give me some examples?

```
<?php
            include('config/config.php'); 
            $ch       = curl_init();
            $username = '**************';
            $password = ''**************';';
            $hash     = base64_encode($username . ':' . $password);
            $headers  = array(
                'Authorization: Basic ' . $hash
            );
            $query = $connection->query("SELECT id_xyz_ro as prods FROM stock_prods where id_xyz_ro > 0");
            $array = Array();
            while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                $array[] = $result['prods'];
            }


            $connection->query('SET session group_concat_max_len=15000');
            foreach($connection->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'', id_xyz_ro, '\'')) as prods FROM stock_prods where id_xyz_ro > 0") as $row) {
            }

            $datas    = array(
                    'id' => $array,
                    'itemsPerPage' => '100', //Only 100 because API it's limiting me at 100 shows per page
                    'currentPage' => '1' //Here I need to loop
            );

            $data = array(
                'data' => $datas

            );
            set_time_limit(0);
            $url = "www.xyz.net/api-3/product_offer/read";
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            print_r($result); //After loop I need to print results from all loops
  ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is sometimes a 'control' part of the response you get which tells you how many items there are and things like what is in the current request.  If there is - can you show it in your question as this may help.

Comment: @NigelRen No, there is not this is the entire code which comunicate with the API and when I'm increasing the value of itemsPerPage to 101 for example, I'm getting: `messages: ["Reading products is limited to maximum 100 elements"]`

So I need to loop the request and make requests (by changing pages after each request) until it's not showing any results, I think